# Is there a way to get a historical data about venues using foursquare API

Tags: python, data-science, foursquare

I am trying to build a racing bar chart with the most trending venue categories (e.g. Italian, cafes, american food restaurant, gym, park,.....) in a specific city over specific a time range, say (2005-current).

For that I am using FOURSQUARE API. I know how to make the request and process the data to get the 10 most common Venues in Paris **NOW**. what I want is to get ***past datasets from e.g. 2005 to current.***

Someone could point me, *if at all possible,*  to the method of getting historical dateset of FOURSQUARE Venues Explore? so i can get e.g. the 10 most common venues in Paris in 2005-current

(probably I need to specify date in EXPLORE URL request to Foursquare API?)

so far, what i think i am getting is real time data.